# Where do I create a MongoDB document with mongoose in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to figure out where in the project structure I can create a mongoDB document instance for which I defined a schema before.

I defined my connection in the main index.js file for mongoDB:

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var express = require('express');
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/db");
```

and created the schema  and document model of the schema inside the "/model" subfolder. I also created an instance of the document schema model and used the method .save() on it, however, nothing happened when I looked inside MongoDB Compass. No database or collection was created.

```
var mySchema = new mongoose.Schema({name: String, count: Number});
var Test = mongoose.model("Test", mySchema);

var test1 = new Test({name: "Clinton", count: 5});
test1.save(function (err) {
if (err) return handleError(err);
// saved!
});;
```

Can someone explain me what I have to do to see the created documents, or where I have to define my document instances inside the Node.js structure?

I use express 4.0 with mongoose and some predefined template structures, I am pretty new to the Node.js stack and so I am not sure if I get it right with the complex structure.
I started the program in cmd with node index.js. It started and listened on port 3000, but not database or collections / documents were created...

Comment: If you want send a message to "me" then you need to use the `@` otherwise I'm just not going to see it. Forget the express part and simply try and create a simple listing which connects to mongoose and attempts to create something. You were pointed at the "basics" because you have not yet demonstrated you understand the basics, and I don't see a clear pattern here that demonstrates a valid connection "which awaits a callback" to even get to the state to be able to create a collection or document. If you can show something "reproducible", then there is something to look at.

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the question, which you have marked @NeilLunn Regardless of the other points you have mentioned. This is a message for "you". Not sure what all the "quotes" around parts of your "sentence" that don't need them are about.

Comment: OP, can you please post more of your code, as requested by Neil? Would like to help you out.

Comment: somehow , I needed additional code to open a db connection, it was not sufficient what I saw on other tutorials. I got this from scotch.io: var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));

db.once('open', function() {
console.log("DB connection alive");
}); after that, I had a connection to mongoDB and could insert and find new objects / documents